# How much time have the Straw Hats spent with each other?

Tags: one-piece

Rewatching a few episodes of One Piece made me wonder:

How much time did the Straw Hats spend with each other **before** the timeskip?  *[It's not necessary for all of them to be present. I'm looking for the time span between the Episode 3 (when Zoro joins the crew) and Episode 405 (when the Straw Hats are separated by Kuma)]*

How much time has it been **since** the timeskip (till the start of Zou arc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several people have wondered this same thing before, and have done plenty of research on the topic. Below I've compiled a couple of the more popular ideas on the passage of time in the One Piece universe.

There was a [similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/2j8a0m/how_much_time_has_passed_in_the_one_piece_world/?ref=share&ref_source=link) asked on Reddit:

### **How much time has passed in the One Piece world?**

To which Redditor [/u/jaydoubleyoutee](https://www.reddit.com/user/jaydoubleyoutee) responded:

> Time in the East Blue is close to impossible to map out.
>   Grand Line is a bit easier though. Loguetown, Reverse Mountain, and Whiskey Peak are the same day. They leave Whiskey Peak the 2nd day. Then several days pass when they reach Little Garden so I'm guessing it's been a week now. They are attacked by Wapol on the 8th day and reach Drum on the 9th. Four days pass and they meet Mr. 2. Five days til they get to Alabasta. The war breaks out two days later. Luffy sleeps for 3 days. They leave the next day, then get to Jaya the same day. They get to Skypiea the next morning and defeat Enel the day after that. So it's been like a month at this point.
>   Then they reach Longring Longland and stay for four days. Three days later they reach Water 7. The next day is the Aqua Laguna. That night they raid Enies Lobby up until the next day. Luffy rests for two days when Garp shows up. Sunny is built in three days and they leave. Several days later, they reach Thriller Bark. They defeat Moriah at sunrise the next day. They sleep for one whole day when Brook joins. They leave two days later. So all this is between three and four weeks.
>   Several more days pass when they arrive at Sabaody. Luffy is sent flying by Kuma and reaches Amazon Lily the next day. He wakes up from the mushroom after a day and befriends Hancock. Five days later they reach Impel Down. The next day is the war. Two weeks pass when Luffy wakes up at Marineford. So about a month has passed since they left Thriller Bark when Luffy decides to train for 2 years.
>   Post-timeskip, it's only been three days. They reach Fishman Island and stay for a day. They leave and go to Punk Hazard. The third day is now on Dressrosa.

[A comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/2n9kfz/how_much_time_has_passed_since_the_timeskip/cmbo18b), coincidentally by the same Redditor, on [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/2n9kfz/how_much_time_has_passed_since_the_timeskip/) explains the 3 days post-timeskip:

> Day 1: Straw Hats arrive at Sabaody. Go to Fishman Island. Beat Hody and challenge Big Mom. Tea Party in 4 days. Will take Pekoms and Tamago 3 days to get there.
>   Day 2: Camie asks for the day off, so it can't be Day 1 since she had that day off too. Straw Hats leave Fishman Island and make an alliance with Law on Punk Hazard.
>   Day 3: Law says on Day 2 that the paper in the morning will have Doflamingo's resignation. They reach Dressrosa that day. Pekoms and Tamago are still on their voyage to Big Mom.

Another way that people have tried to pinpoint the amount of time is the moon cycles that Oda depicts during night time scenes in the manga. Here is an excerpt from the [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mythbusters/Speculations) on this matter:

> In One Piece, Oda has depicted the moon several times, it has been discovered the moon's phases progress with the storyline's own timeline and therefore it can be used as a judge for the number of days that have passed on their journey. However from the first sighting in the Syrup Village Arc (waxing crescent) to the start of the Amazon Lily arc (waning crescent) would work out to be only 21 days by this guide. Although due to certain conditions on one of the phases seen, it could be as much as 42 days.

One point to be made is that we know the characters have only aged 2 years, the length of the timeskip. So the time spent pre-timeskip is definitely less than a year. Based off the information I've shared above, it's more likely to be just a couple months.

It definitely feels very strange when you consider how long we've been watching their journey, and I think Oda sensee agrees since he made this joke in [SBS Volume 24](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_24):

> Q: It takes while for time to pass in manga, doesn't it? Since it's a weekly thing. So, should we wait like 2 more years for Luffy's birthday?
>
> A: No, no, no. He has a birthday every year, just like everyone else. It's just that, in Luffy's case, every year is his 17th birthday. Doesn't that make you jealous?

Comment: Yeah, that feels really weird. I knew they had spent less than a year based on their ages, but 21-42 days. Damn :|

Comment: when the straw hat crew reach red line just before Sabaody  they remark about how they are at the half way point of the grand line and that it has taken 1 year to get there.

Comment: Do you have an episode number or chapter number?

Comment: @Skeith, in the manga, chapter 490, page 9 and 10, no reference is made to how long they traveled to get there. Only the more recent additions to the crew, (Robin, Franky and Brooke), comment on how long ago they entered the grand line. Oda sure makes it feel like it took forever to get there though, with how the crew express themselves. But the manga does not define it to 1 year, and I doubt the anime would change that, but I haven't checked.

Comment: about the final note, it is known as the "Lum's law". In Urusei Yatsura you have like 5 end of year episodes, 10 Christmas episodes and a load of "summer just came" episodes. Ataru.. is still 17 at the end. Atlas, in Lum case you can just advocate that Beautiful Dreamer never ended. She got her wish granted...

Answer (score 1):

[This reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/cp7j5j/how_much_time_has_passed_in_one_piece/ewnuxu1) has gone through the manga and noted the days. I have confirmed some by diving into the manga at certain points. Below is the comment, copy pasted. All credit to the original commentator, please.

> I tried to go through the Manga...
>
> East Blue Saga : about 15 days, Grand Line : About 77 days, New World
> : about 41 days
>
> Total : 2 years 134 days or about 2 years and 4 months
>
> ** - (didn't seem to have food to travel for more than a day)
>
> Day 1 : Luffy leaves Fuusha Village
>
> Day 2** :  Luffy is sucked into a whirlpool and ends up in Alvida's
> base
>
> Day 3** : Luffy and Coby free Zoro
>
> Day 4** : Luffy and Zoro reach Orange town, meet Gaimon
>
> Day 5** : Luffy arrives at Syrup Village
>
> Day 6 : Luffy defeats Kuro
>
> Day 7 : Usopp joins, Strawhats get Merry, Usopp paints the Strawhat
> Jolly Roger, Strawhats meet Johnny and Yosaku
>
> Day 10 : (Johnny says it takes 2-3 days to reach Baratie) Strawhats
> reach Baratie
>
> Day 11 : (it says 2 days later) Don Krieg attacks Baratie and is
> defeated, sanji joins, Nami arrives at Arlong Park, Zoro is captured,
> Nami frees Zoro, Luffy arrives at Arlong park, Luffy defeats Arlong,
> party through the night
>
> Day 13 : Cocoyashi village still parties
>
> Day 14 : Luffy leaves Cocoyashi village
>
> Day 15 : Luffy finds out his bounty, Luffy arrives in Loguetown, is
> almost executed, leaves loguetown
>
> Since entering Grand Line..
>
> Day 1 : Arrive at Twin Capes, get Log Pose, head to Whiskey Peak,
> reach Whiskey peak at sun down, spend the night at whiskey peak.
>
> Day 2 : Leave Whiskey peak in the morning, arrive at little garden,
> leave little garden.
>
> Day 5 : (Kureha tells Nami that she had been infected for 3 days)
> Arrive at Drum kingdom, leave Drum kingdom at night.
>
> Day 10 : (stated that 5 days have passed since leaving Drum kingdom)
> Meet Bon Clay on their way to Alabasta.
>
> Day 14 (atleast) : (Luffy says its been 4 days since he last ate)
> Arrive at Alabasta, meet Ace, reach Yuba at night
>
> Day 15 : Leave Yuba in the morning, change plans and head to rainbase.
>
> Day 16 : (Vivi said Rainbase was a day's walk from Yuba) Reach
> Rainbase, head for Alubarna, Luffy beats crocodile.
>
> Day 19 : (Vivi says Luffy was sleeping for 3 days) Luffy wakes up,
> Strawhats leave Alubarna at night to find Merry.
>
> Day 20 : Bid farewell to Vivi and leave Alabasta, find Robin on their
> ship, a ship falls from the sky, Strawhats head for Jaya, Luffy beats
> Bellamy.
>
> Day 21 : Strawhats ride the Knock-up Stream to Skypiea, spend the
> night planning on finding golden city.
>
> Day 22 : Luffy defeats Enel, party at night
>
> Day 23 : Strawhats leave skypiea
>
> Day 24 (maybe) : Strawhats arrive at Long ring Long Land, win the Davy
> Back fight, lose to Aokiji.
>
> Day 28 : (It says that Luffy and Robin needed to rest for 4 days after
> being frozen) Strawhats arrive at Water 7, Usopp fights Luffy, Robin
> tries to assassinate Iceburg at night
>
> Day 29 : Strawhats try to meet Robin at night, face CP9, lose, set out
> for Enies Lobby
>
> Day 30 : CP9 is defeated, Strawhats bid farewell to Merry.
>
> Day 32 : (It says 2 days since the incident) Franky promises to build
> Sunny, Luffy meets Garp
>
> Day 35 : (It says 3 days after waiting for Sunny) Strawhats leave
> Water 7 on board Sunny.
>
> Day 36 (probably) : Strawhats enter thriller bark, beat moria before
> dawn
>
> Day 37 : Zoro takes Luffy's pain, Brook joins the crew
>
> Day 39 : (It says 2 days later) Zoro wakes up, Strawhats leave
> Thriller Bark.
>
> Day 44 (may be) : (It says several days later) Strawhats reach the Red
> Line, rescue Hacchi, head to Saboady, get sent away by Kuma.
>
> Day 47 : (Sentoumaru says people sent by Kuma fly for 3 days) Luffy
> arrives at Amazon Lily, fights Boa sisters, parties at night, finds
> out about Ace's execution, leaves Amazon Lily at night.
>
> Day 53 : (Gloriosa said Ace was about to be executed in 6 days)
> Paramount war, Ace dies, Luffy escapes on Law's submarine
>
> Day 67 : (It says 2 weeks since Paramount war) Luffy wakes up, meets
> Rayleigh, decides to take a 2 year time skip
>
> Day 72 (may be) : (assuming it takes 5 days to reach marineford from
> amazon lily) Luffy sends the message 3D2Y to the crew
>
> Day 77 (maybe) : (5 days return journey) Luffy starts training on
> Rusukaina.
>
> 2 years later...
>
> Day 1 : Arrive at Saboady, reach fishman island, defeat Hody, party
> through the night.
>
> Day 2 : Leave fishman island, arrive at Punk Hazard, defeat Caesar,
> leave Punk Hazard
>
> Day 3 : Doffy's resignation announced, crew arrives at dressrosa,
> defeats Doffy, half the crew head to zou.
>
> Day 13 : (they say Jack left 10 days ago because of Doffy's defeat)
> rest of the crew arrives at Zou, parties though the night
>
> Day 14 : Kinemon reaches the top of the elephant, Robin deciphers the
> road poneglyph, Jack attacks Zou, Zunesha defeats Jack, half the crew
> leaves for Tottoland
>
> Day 21 : (assuming it took 1 week to reach Tottoland) Luffy arrives at
> Cacao island
>
> Day 22 : Luffy arrives at Whole Cake island, fights Cracker through
> the night
>
> Day 23 : Sanji beats Luffy, Luffy fights the enraged Army, is
> captured, escapes, eats Sanji's food
>
> Day 24 : Luffy meets Bege, Tea party is ruined, Luffy fights Katakuri,
> the crew escapes Tottoland at night
>
> Day 25 : Luffy is announced the fifth emperor, Revolutionaries save
> Lulusia kingdom
>
> Day 27 : (2 days after Lulusia kingdom is saved) Reverie begins
>
> Day 31 : (we get the news of the 4th day of reverie) Moria invades
> Blackbeard's island, Act 2 begins, Luffy beats Dobon
>
> Day 32 : Komurasaki dies
>
> Day 33 : Komurasaki's wake is cancelled
>
> Day 34 : Komurasaki's funeral, Yasuie dies, Big mom arrives in Udon,
> Udon is conquered by Luffy, Big mom and Kaido clash
>
> Day 36 : Big mom and Kaido form an Alliance
>
> Day 41 : (one week since Reverie ends) Raid on Onigashima begins on
> the day of the Fire festival

Answer (score 0):

Just look at Coby. Before, he was just a teenager (16) when Luffy and Zorro met him. But when they meet him again in the Water 7 arc, he is already a preadult (17).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere its said that the pre-time skip lasts for about nine months, while the post is still less than two month in. So the post-timeskip is true, but there is more spacing in the events of the pre-timeskip.

Comment: Where is this "somewhere"? Can you share a source?